# Imaginatively yours or Yours imaginatively or stick with Kind Regards

Tags: email, valediction

I own a design studio. We are currently rebranding. To add a little twist to our email correspondence, we decided to forego the generic "Kind regards" for imaginatively yours or yours imaginatively. Would that be appropriate in this case?

Example:

```
Dear Jane


Thank you again for your continued business.


Imaginatively yours,

Stalin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Imaginatively yours," makes more sense, as does "Sincerely yours," and so forth. "Yours truly" is the most common exception, of course, but "Yours imaginatively" sounds too contrived to my ear. As the owner of a design studio, your use of "Imaginatively yours" seems quite appropriate.